# flutter rebuild Widget when keyboard is open/closed then function call again

Tags: flutter, dart

> working with story view
> and want to comment on each story when when keyboard is open call story controller pause >function
> issue is that when open keyboard widget build call again and and morestory function start again >then story controller  play function
> how to stop rebuild widget

````
        body: SizedBox(
          height: height,
          width: width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned.fill(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onLongPress: () {
                    setState(() {
                      crewLongPress = true;
                    });
                  },
                  onLongPressEnd: (details) {
                    setState(() {
                      crewLongPress = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: MoreStories(userSameStory, controller),
                ),
              ),
             Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                                          child: buildTextField(height, width),
                                        ),])) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to "dispose" your controller after every action.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement "lazy loading" functionality in you application